# Cannot add mysql entity data model

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013

I added to my project nuget packages of MySql.Data (6.9.6) and MySql.Data.Entity (6.9.6). While installing they automatically added Entity Framework 6.0.0.
Now, when I am adding ADO.NET Entity Data Model, in choose your version screen I see this:

[image]

I tried updating MySql dlls in Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies folder as was suggested in some of the posts.

Any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your 'app.config' file with the following in the provider section under `<entityFramework>`:

```
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6"></provider>
```

After that, rebuild and you should no longer have any issues.